# How to run a function objects in array in prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototypejs

I have a Prototype class which has a function removeMarker.

```
var Location = Class.create({
    removeMarker: function(){
        // Some code here to remove a marker from a map
    }
});
```

I have an array of these:

```
var locations = [];
```

Is there an easy way to invoke `removeMarker()` on every location object in the array?

At the moment I am using:

```
locations.each(function(l,i) {
    l.removeMarker();
});
```

I am sure I have seen something using `.map()` or `.invoke()` but running

```
 locations.invoke(removeMarker);
```

doesn't seem to work. I know I am just doing something stupid, just need someone to point it out...

Comment: `each` and `invoke` are definitely not native JavaScript methods. I don't understand what your question has to do with prototypes and enumerable properties.

Comment: @FelixKling: question title. "Prototype" offers/extends boths methods.

Comment: @jAndy: Oh... I was too much thinking about, you know, prototype inheritance... nvm. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry felix, should have said I was using Prototype framework!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `removeMarker` between apostrophes.

So:
    locations.invoke('removeMarker');